# Calculating ratio to maximum in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, max

I have this table in Postgres:

name - varchar, weight and height - int4. I need to compute the ration of weight to maximum weight and height to the maximum height for each record.

So far I have only this:

```
select people.name, people.weight, people.height, people.weight/max(people.weight) 
as weight_ratio, people.height/max(people.height) from people
```

but I get this error: `column "people.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

How do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MAX()` window function:

```
SELECT name, weight, height, 
       weight / MAX(weight) OVER() weight_ratio, 
       height / MAX(height) OVER() height_ratio 
FROM people
```

If `weight` and `height` are integers you should also multiply by `1.0` before the division, because Postgresql performs integer division between integers and will truncate any decimal part:

```
SELECT name, weight, height, 
       1.0 * weight / MAX(weight) OVER() weight_ratio, 
       1.0 * height / MAX(height) OVER() height_ratio 
FROM people
```